# Insert Text Every 34 Character in a Text Document + MAC

Tags: macos, shell, applescript, character

I'm stuck. I need a script that will read my text document and insert custom text on the 34 character. This needs to happen for every line in my text document.

Example:

INPUT TEXT

```
`12345678912345678912345678912345  ABCD`
`12345678912345678912345678912345  EFGH`
`12345678912345678912345678912345  IJKL`
`12345678912345678912345678912345  MNOP`
```

OUTPUT TEXT

```
`12345678912345678912345678912345 custom text hereABCD`
`12345678912345678912345678912345 custom text hereEFGH`
`12345678912345678912345678912345 custom text hereIJKL`
`12345678912345678912345678912345 custom text hereMNOP`
```

I've provided below the script I can get working within Terminal.  However, if there is a way to get it to work in Applescript so when I drop my file on the application it will prompt and ask what text I would like to insert (this would be "custom text here") and then upon hitting OK it would run.

If it isn't possible to do in Applescript, Automator would work too however, I cannot seem to get Automator to work with the script.  Process for Automator is:

```
1. Get Specified Finder Items
2. Run Shell Script
```

This runs fine, but it does not change the document.  Help?

Comment: Please specify accurately what you want. Expected input, expected output, and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bash you can use `while read -r -N 34` to read 34 characters repeatedly. Untested example:

```
while IFS= read -r -N 34 || [[ -n "$REPLY" ]]
do
    printf '%s' "$REPLY"
    printf '%s\n' " custom text here"
done < input-file
```

Update: Looks like OP wants to *discard* characters after #34 on each line:

```
while IFS= read -r || [[ -n "$REPLY" ]]
do
    printf '%s' "${REPLY:0:34}"
    printf '%s\n' " custom text here"
done < input-file
```

UPDATE: OP here and I've figured out based on your wonderful knowledge everything I need to do!

```
while IFS= read -r || [[ -n "$REPLY" ]]
do
    printf '%s' "${REPLY:0:34}"
    printf '%s' "  Faux_Folder/"
    printf '%s\n' "${REPLY:36}"
done < input-file > output-file
```

Comment: The logic seems good, but I am doubtful, if this works for files containing newlines. Failed on my ubuntu system at least...

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong. When I put this into Automators Shell Script as arguments, first asking to get specified finder items, after it runs it doesn't do anything. I've tried it with removing the < input-file  and also putting in < DRIVE.txt (as that is what my input file is).

Comment: @EvanGervais Works for me and anishsane. What **exactly** did you run and on **exactly** what input?

Comment: I first went into terminal and changed the directory to my desktop where the text file is.  I then entered the SED script provided changing the "input.txt" to match my file name.  This brings back the error "Bad flag in substitute command '}'.

For the other, this is what I put into automator
1. Get specified Finder Items (bring in DRIVE.TXT)
2. Run Shell Script:
while IFS= read -r -N 34 || [[ -n "$REPLY" ]]
do
    printf '%s' "$REPLY"
    printf '%s\n' " custom text here"
done < DRIVE.txt

My apologies. New to this site and new to doing scripting. Trying to help someone at work on my down tim

Comment: I finally got the bash to work within Terminal. However, the file I have as text on the same line after the 34th character. IS there a way to ad the "custom text here" at the 34th character count on a line, then jump down to the next line and add same text?  Also, is there a way for the script to output a new text document with the changes?

Comment: If there are characters after the insert of "custom text here" they would like us to keep it. If it is a quick fix to the bash to do this, and also a way to put it into a new text file, that would be awesome!

Comment: I have successfully kept the text afterwards.  Only thing I'm working on now is saving this as a new text file or overwriting the file I just created.

Comment: @l0b0 the way the edited script provided was working was adding the " custom text here" or as my colleague was test " Faux_Folder". However, it would remove the characters afterwards.  I found that if I added the last line with 36 it would keep the characters after and line up right after the custom text. Some miscommunication from others about this, that is why there was a lot of confusion to start. Needless to say, everything is working now, I'm just trying to get this to work in Automator now with no luck

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this work on OSX (works on ubuntu at least.):

```
sed -n -E '1h;2,$H;${g;s/.{34}/& custom text here\n/gp}' input.txt
```

Basically, it reads till the end of file & then inserts " custom text here\n" after every 34 characters.

Comment: This solution is time optimized. Other solution is memory optimized :-)

Comment: I have another "sed" script that works on Mac OSX. I have it set in Automator to get specified finder items, then run a shell script as arguments.  It works however, if I use the script above it does not.  Of course, I maybe be doing something completely wrong.

Comment: If the default sed on your system is your sed script, then you may try to use absolute path to sed binary instead of just `sed` in my solution.